# [Java]org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I have around 24 GB of records which I am reading and processing in spark from cassandra. I have used flatmaptopair and filter transformation and is then storing the RDD using datastax cassandra connector. But while performing the action of saving to cassandra my executors fail and it start throwing the following exception-

```
16/03/17 03:00:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.1 in stage 3.0 (TID 133, 10.0.0.65): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=0, mapId=-1, reduceId=11, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:456)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On checking the exectur logs its showing following error-

> ERROR MapOutputTracker: Missing an output location for shuffle 0

Once it throws the exception spark restarts all the stages again. My cluster is of 2 nodes with 16 GB memory and 4 cores. I am running spark as standalone cluster with 12 gb assigned to each worker node. Also when I am running the job in my local machine with 10 GB of data its working perfectly fine. I have tried with changing the persistance level to DISK_ONLY and MEMORY_AND_DISK but to no avail.

Edit 1-

I have been able to figure out that the shuffling is failing when I am doing reduce by key operation as for one key a its aggregating records amounting to 250 mb. Here is my snippet for reducebykey-

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Products[]> categoryMapCollection=categoryMapFiltered.reduceByKey(
                new Function2<Products[], Products[], Products[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public Products[] call(Products[] p1,Products[] p2)
                    {
                        Products[] both = (Products[])ArrayUtils.addAll(p1, p2);
                        return both;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You want to look at the log files on the failing executors - not the log file from the master. This type of error is (nearly) always due to OOM exceptions and they will be logged in the executor log files.

Comment: Checked the logs at executor node, it shows following error-  ERROR MapOutputTracker: Missing an output location for shuffle 0.

Comment: Like Glennie mentioned, it is probably OOM, i have ran into similar issue,can you try to use MEMORY_AND_DISK or DISK_ONLY to prove it may be OOM.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/programming-guide.html

Comment: I am already using DISK_ONLY for setting persistent level. I think the issue is in shuffling of data.

Comment: _Missing an output location_ simply means that another executor has failed before the one you're looking at. Look through the other executor logs as well. Even if you use DISK_ONLY, you have to remember that each of the "active" partitions (meaning the partitions currently worked on) have to fit in memory. OOMs in Spark are frequently caused by a few partitions growing beyond the memory limit. Repartitioning the data will usually help with this, but I strongly urge you to locate the error in the logs to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: This is happening when I am performing reducebykey operation in my job. I checked the stage whenever there is some huge set of data coming corresponding to a key(around 250 MB) its throwing this exception.

Comment: hey, @Y0geshGupta, did you get this solved? How? I am also facing a similar error

Comment: Nope, the issue was arising due to less memory available in my machine. I had to change my approach to make it work.

Comment: @Y0geshGupta can u please share the approach?